# Multiple dropdown buttons – only one open at a time (JS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create two language selection dropdown buttons. I succeeded using [this W3Schools template](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown). However, this solution has two drawbacks:
1. you need (?) one script per dropdown button or modification of that script;
2. you can have two dropdown buttons open at the same time, which I don't want.

I found a solution to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353381/3918419), but I cannot seem to be able to adapt it to dropdown buttons. I tried to rework it step-by-step, but I cannot get rid of  nested in .

**How can I create multiple dropdown buttons, so that they use one JS/jQuery script (preferably without Bootstrap), and so that opening one dropdown closes any other currently open dropdown?**

**Edit:**
This is the code in my page I have now:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn"><img src="img/flags/en.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">English</span>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div id="lang2" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/en.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">English</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/fr.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">French</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/de.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">German</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/ru.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Russian</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/pl.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Polish</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/cz.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Czech</span></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/flags/zh.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Mandarin</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/1e6ebh7z/) is the furthest I ever got without breaking the dropdowns. I tried replacing the outside `<ul>`s with  and update the css accordingly, but somehow it didn't work as intended. I also tried applying is-open where dropdown-content is.

Comment: Could you add some parts of your code for better comprehension ?

Comment: you said already reworked something, please provide the codes you tried so far in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Sure, added as per request (for whatever it's worth).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I modified the W3Schools template to make it work with 2 dropdowns menus that can't be opened at the same time with just a little modification of the script.
This solution works with vanilla JavaScript. Some could prefer jQuery.

Please see below the code, I commented some parts:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
closes every dropdowns and open the only one passed as argument */

/* Javascript only */
function myFunction(element) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  
  // element.nextSibling is the carriage return… The dropdown menu is the next next.
  var thisDropdown = element.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  
  if (!thisDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {  // Added to hide dropdown if clicking on the one already open
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      dropdowns[i].classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
  
  // Toggle the dropdown on the element clicked
  thisDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
}

/* W3Schools function to close the dropdown when clicked outside. */
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">Dropdown1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Added 2nd dropdown ! -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a proposition of utilisation of `this` using `nextSibling`, as an example.

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

A jQuery solution, for those who prefer.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
closes every dropdowns and open the only one passed as argument */

/* jQuery */
function myFunction(element) {
  var elements = ".dropdown-content";
  $(elements).removeClass('show');
  $(element).next(elements).toggleClass("show");
}

/* W3Schools function to close the dropdown when clicked outside. */
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">Dropdown1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this);" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This is very nice! 1. Can this be edited so that clicking outside of the dropdowns also closes them? Also: 2. do I understand correctly that this `for` iterates through all dropdowns to close them? 3. can I use `this` instead of an ID in pure JS?

Comment: 1. Of course the clicking outside functionnality can be added. I added it right now by copying the one of the W3C example. 2. You understand correctly, the `for` iterates through all the instances of the class "dropdown-content". 3. Yes, `this` can be used in pure JS. I am going to make an edit and propose something using it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, works exactly as intended, plus the explanations were really helpful :)

Comment: How can we close the dropdown by clicking the same dropdown button?

Comment: @Ulvi I've modified my code to do it in my JavaScript snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a short solution using jquery. U can have unlimited dropdowns with only one script.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
$('.dropDown').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $('.drop').removeClass('drop');
    $(this).addClass('drop');
  })
})
```

```css
.drop-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-content {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.drop+.nav-content {
  display: block;
}

.nav-content a .drop-item {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="live.html">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="stock" class="dropDown">Drop1</a>
    <div class="nav-content">
      <a class="drop-item first" href="#">SubItem1</a>
      <a class="drop-item" href="#">SubItem2</a>
      <a class="drop-item" href="#">SubItem3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="videos" class="dropDown">Drop2</a>
    <div class="nav-content">
      <a class="drop-item first" href="">SubItem1</a>
      <a class="drop-item" href="">SubItem2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, while dropdowns in navbar aren't that much of a problem, I am struggling to combine stand-alone dropdown buttons with two buttons closing each other functionality, and closing by clicking outside of them. Could that easily be done?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `.each(function() {` to `removeClass` on all the elements in your function…   Wouldn't be better to simply do `$('.drop').removeClass('drop');` ?

Comment: @TakitIsy I dont know why i allways look for a ``each()`` solution. Will edit, thanks :)