# dropdown open only one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this dropdown multiple times and want only one to be open (the others when i click to close):

```js
$(".dropdown-tree-a").click(function () { 
     if($(this).parents().hasClass('open-tree'))
     {
         $(this).parent().removeClass("open-tree")
     }
     $(this).parent('.dropdown-tree').toggleClass("open-tree active"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown-tree">
       <a class="dropdown-tree-a"> <span class="badge pull-right">42</span> WOMEN COLLECTION </a>
       <ul class="category-level-2 dropdown-menu-tree">
           <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Shirt </a></li>
           <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Fragrances </a></li>
           <li><a href="sub-category.html">Scarf </a></li>
           <li><a href="sub-category.html">Sandal </a></li>
           <li><a href="sub-category.html">Winter Collection </a></li>
           <li><a href="sub-category.html">Men Accessories </a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
```

when click on ".dropdown-tree-a"  the current dropdown is opened but the others don't close (remove the class open-tree)

Can someone please tell me what i did wrong?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try `$('.open-tree').removeClass('open-tree active');` instead of if statement.

Comment: @jcubic works! :) thx

Comment: @calin24 check this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjozwg?editors=1010.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914111/multiple-dropdown-buttons-only-one-open-at-a-time-js-jquery

Answer (score 0):

here is the most simple & easy solution

```js
   jQuery(".dropdown-tree-a").click(function (e) {                     
                    e.preventDefault();
    
       jQuery(".dropdown-tree").removeClass("open-tree active"); 
       /** FIRST REMOVE CLASSES FROM ALL ELEMENTS **/
       jQuery(this).parents('.dropdown-tree').addClass("open-tree active"); 
       /** IN NEXT STEP FIND PARENT item with class '.dropdown-tree' and then add classes 'open-tree active'. USe Css to display child items **/
    });
```

```css
li.dropdown-tree ul.dropdown-menu-tree{
  display:none;
}

li.dropdown-tree.open-tree.active ul.dropdown-menu-tree{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-tree">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-tree-a"> <span class="badge pull-right">42</span> WOMEN COLLECTION </a>
   <ul class="category-level-2 dropdown-menu-tree">
       <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Shirt </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Fragrances </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Scarf </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Sandal </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Winter Collection </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Men Accessories </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>

<li class="dropdown-tree">
   <a  href="#" class="dropdown-tree-a"> <span class="badge pull-right">42</span> WOMEN COLLECTION </a>
   <ul class="category-level-2 dropdown-menu-tree">
       <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Shirt </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html"> Fragrances </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Scarf </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Sandal </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Winter Collection </a></li>
       <li><a href="sub-category.html">Men Accessories </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```