# Multiple dropdown menus triggering on the same click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914449) which seems to trigger the `slideToggle` event for both drop-down menus. I can't seem to find a solution to triggering only the child drop-down menu of the clicked `li` element.

A jQuery solution would be best if possible!

```js
var hi = $( '.header-item.has-sub' );
var hdd = hi.children( '.header-sub' );

hi.each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        hdd.toggleClass( 'open' );
        hdd.slideToggle( 'fast' );
    });
});
```

```css
ul li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-menu">

    <li class="header-item">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-cog"></i>
            <span>Settings</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="header-item has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-bell"></i>
            <span>Notifications</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="header-sub">

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
                    <span>Details</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-map-marker"></i>
                    <span>Address</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-signout"></i>
                    <span>Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="header-item has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
            <span>Profile</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="header-sub">

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
                    <span>Details</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-map-marker"></i>
                    <span>Address</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-signout"></i>
                    <span>Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: hi, perhaps grab the children of the clicked element in the click handler `"var children = $(this).children('.header-sub'); children.slideToggle(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check in your click event

```js
$('.header-item.has-sub').click(function() {
    var hdd = $(this).find('ul.header-sub');
    $(hdd).toggleClass('open').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
ul li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-menu">

    <li class="header-item">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-cog"></i>
            <span>Settings</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="header-item has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-bell"></i>
            <span>Notifications</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="header-sub">

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
                    <span>Details</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-map-marker"></i>
                    <span>Address</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-signout"></i>
                    <span>Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="header-item has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
            <span>Profile</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="header-sub">

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
                    <span>Details</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-map-marker"></i>
                    <span>Address</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="uil uil-signout"></i>
                    <span>Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```